# How to use shuf command as a variable

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, command

My goal is to use shuf command to pick random files from directory and use as input for ffmpeg stream.

ffmpeg command: ./ffmpeg -i file

ls | shuf -n 1 output gives me a random file name, which is what I need but how do I incorporate this into ffmpeg command? If i store it into a variable, the variable out outputs shuf output from the time when variable was stored.

fileshuf=$(ls | shuf -n 1)
echo $fileshuf only outputs same file name

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

every time you run

```
./ffmpeg -i $(ls | shuf -n 1)
```

you'll get a random file

Comment: Also, `./ffmpeg -i "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 | shuf -z -n 1)"` is the equivalent but more filename safe version of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | shuf -n 1 | xargs ./ffmpeg -i
```

would be my quick, dirty and effective suggestion:-)